# Pease explain why does the phase bw two sidebands in PDH method changes from pi (when laser is at perfect resonance with cavity) due to dithering?

Tags: laser, ligo, laser-cavity

since, this signal is compared with the original modulating signal and the net phase shift gives the error signal which is fed to the servo for control. Hence, knowledge of phase deviation due to frequency dithering is important to finalize the parameters of the FP etalon. What relation to follow to get the information of phase shift due to laser frequency dithering.